# c# different delegate add in dictionary and run deleagate method from dictionary

Tags: c#, reflection, functional-programming, delegates

With C#

I want to my delegate method into one dictionary, and put them all out and run.

for example

```
class class1{

Func<string,int> method1 = new Func<string,int>( x => 3);
Func<int,double> method2 = new Func<string,int>( x => 3.0);
Func<double,bool> method3 = new Func<string,int>( x => true);

Dictionary<string, dynamic> dic = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

dic.add("m1",method1)
dic.add("m2",method2)
dic.add("m3",method3)

// rund all method 

dynamic RunMethod(Dictionary<string, dynamic> dic , dynamic firstInput, int index = 0)
{
  if(index = dic.count) return 
  RunMethod(dic, dic.ElementAt[index].value(input) , index + 1)
}

void main ()
{
 RunMethod( dix , "firstString" )
}
}
```

(this code has error but expression of what i want to do )

What i want to do is like below.

1. Create Method 1, 2 ,3
2. Output type of Method 1 = Input type of Method2 ,
   Output type of Method 2 = Input type of Method3
   Finally get output of Method3
3. There is Run Method that take Input that has type of method1 and method dictionary (or list or something)
4. I want to additional method that check what type of method 1? and output type of method 3

Comment: And where is your problem?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why don't you just chain the methods together as a regular method?

Comment: Also, why are you using a `Dictionary`? I can't see its keys used anywhere.

Comment: The keys are strings added above

Comment: The reason why i do this is for seperate definition of sequance and run. Like tensorflow. The whole plan is create framework , that covert multi threading with multi agent system that part of complex system.

Comment: The reason why using dictionary is for readability and adaptivity. This style is for super dynamic enviroment that need frequently modify code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you exactly looking for. This code sample may help you.

```
    class Class1
            {
                public Func<string, int> method1 = new Func<string, int>(x => 3);
                public Func<int, double> method2 = new Func<int, double>(x => 4.0);
                public Func<double, bool> method3 = new Func<double, bool>(x => true);

                List<Delegate> methodList = new List<Delegate>();

                public Class1()
                {
                    methodList.Add(method1);
                    methodList.Add(method2);
                    methodList.Add(method3);
                }

                public object RunMethods(object param)
                {
                    foreach(Delegate del in methodList)
                    {
                        param = del.DynamicInvoke(param);
                    }

                    return param;
                }
            }

 static void Main(string[] args)
{
       Class1 obj = new Class1();
       object result = obj.RunMethods("some string");
}
```